# Split dataframe columns and rename columns received Type Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split a dataframe column into two columns
The data look like this

```
battery
2-cells Lion
3-cells Lion
Lion
```

Expected result

```
cells    materials
2-cells    Lion
3-cells    Lion
1          Lion
```

I tried `pd.DataFrame(data.battery.str.split(' ', 1).tolist(), columns = ['cells', 'materials'])`
I received `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`
Can someone explain what does this mean and how to write the correct code please ?

Comment: you have `nan` values, just fill them first `df[col].fillna('').str.split(...)`

Comment: @Manakin How to I make the splited columns into new columns in the dataframe ?